# scala lower type bounds example

Tags: scala, types

I have the following code:

```
class A[+X] {
  def printY[Y >: X](y: Y) = println(y)
}

class F
class G extends F

val f = new F
val g = new G

val a = new A[F]
a.printY(g)
```

I expect a compilation error in `a.printY(g)` as `g` has type `G` which is not a supertype of `F`. But in `class A` I indicated that `printY` method only accepts supertype of `A`'s type paramter which is `F` in my example.

Why it works correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: if you *want* `a.printY(g)` not to compile you need to rewrite the method:

```
def printY[Y](y: Y)(implicit ev: X <:< Y) = println(y)
```

This way the compiler infers the type parameter to be `G` and *then* checks whether it's a supertype of `F` instead of looking for a supertype of `F` which also happens to be an acceptable type for `g`.

Comment: +1, Nice addendum. I would also add that you'd still be able to manually set `Y` to `F`: `a.printY[F](g)` - and I don't think that can be prevented.

Comment: @Zapadlo 1. When you e.g. add an `A` to a list of `B`s, you'll get a list of least common supertype of `A` and `B`, which is precisely the behavior you get from lower type bounds; 2. You can get more interesting behavior when the method with a lower type bound on `Y` doesn't just accept `Y`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `g` is *also* an instance of `F`. Therefore, `Y` is inferred as `F`, which is a supertype of `F`. I.e.:

```
a.printY[F](g)
```

However, this wouldn't compile:

```
a.printY[G](g)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to explain why it works from another two angles.

First, as you know the upper bound is **`reflexive`**, for Y >: X, type X or subtype of Y is acceptable. so when you define `val a = new A[F]`, printY will be like:

```
def printY[Y >: F](y: Y) = println(y)
```

when you invoke a.printY(g), printY's type parameter will be inferred as G, which is also a type of F.

Second, for `def printY[Y >: F](y: Y) = println(y)`, when you pass an instance I of type Y, compiler will try to find the **common parent** of I and F and make the resultant type as the type parameter of printY, so you can even pass value of String, Int to printY.

```
a.printY[Any]("xxx")
a.printY[Any](3)
```